# ee_cart_imped doesn't work for real PR2

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I'm just following the tutorial of ee_cart_imped package. It's working for Gazebo, but not for real PR2. I get the following:

```
core service [/rosout] found
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[r_arm_stopper-1]: started with pid [8592]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[r_arm_cart_imped_controller_spawner-2]: started with pid [8593]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[r_arm_cart_imped_controller/r_arm_cart_imped_action_node-3]: started with pid [8594]
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1348693065.095550] Failed to load r_arm_cart_imped_controller
```

Any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44625/ee_cart_imped-doesn%27t-work-for-real-pr2./) by [J](https://answers.ros.org/users/3264/j/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-09-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2012-09-26**:
Which version of ROS are you running? Which version of Ubuntu? Have you built all of the ee_cart_imped_* packages?

**Comment by [J](https://answers.ros.org/users/3264/j/) on 2012-09-27**:
I'm using Fuerte/12.04. I think I've built them because I can see the controller is running in Gazebo... Could you let me know any suggestions or step-by-step instruction which I can follow? Thanks!

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2012-09-28**:
You're running Ubuntu 12.04 on a PR2, or on your desktop?

**Comment by [J](https://answers.ros.org/users/3264/j/) on 2012-09-28**:
I'm running it on my desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since PR2 controllers are dynamic libraries that are loaded from the file system, you need to have them built on your PR2 if you want to run them there, and you should run the relevant launch files on the PR2 rather than on your desktop.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2013-01-17**:
Also, as far as I know, you need to restart the pr2 after building the ee_cart_imped library. Something about the real-time loop I guess.